# How to take max/second max with tiers using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data where I would like to get the following information. Example is based on `ID == 1`.

1. First date of each ID and its corresponding result (for `ID == 1` its `DATE == 1/3/2018`). If there are tiers, take the last row (`RESULT == 110`).
2. Second date of each ID and its corresponding result (for `ID == 1` its `DATE == 2/3/2018`). If there are tiers, take the last row (`RESULT == 117`).
3. Lowest result and its corresponding date. If lowest value has 2 dates, output the first date. The second date will be the date for the second lowest result.
4. Second lowest result and its corresponding date. If lowest value is distinct from the lowest result.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                ID DATE RESULT
                1 1/3/2018 110
                1 1/3/2018 120
                1 2/3/2018 115
                1 2/3/2018 117
                1 3/3/2018 100
                1 4/3/2018 100
                2 1/11/2018 110
                2 1/11/2018 120
                2 1/11/2018 108
                2 2/11/2018 115
                2 3/11/2018 80
                2 4/11/2018 70", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
df_out <- read.table(text = "
                ID FIRST_DATE FIRST_RESULT SECOND_DATE SECOND_RESULT LOWEST_DATE LOWEST_RESULT SECOND_LOWEST_DATE SECOND_LOWEST_RESULT
                1 2018-03-01 120 2018-03-02 117 2018-03-03 100 2018-03-04 100
                2 2018-11-01 108 2018-11-02 115 2018-11-04 70 2018-11-03 80", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Steps Taken:**

1. Split the problem into 2, one that involves ranking by date and the other, involving ranking by result.
2. Use `dplyr::dense_rank` for the first portion and `dplyr::row_number` for the second portion.
3. Take `dplyr::full_join` to get final dataframe.

My code works perfectly, but I feel that it is too long. Hence, I would like to ask if anyone could write this out more concisely.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# First Portion
df_DATE <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE),
         RANK_DATE = dense_rank(DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, RANK_DATE) %>% 
  filter(RANK_DATE %in% 1:2,
         row_number() == n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(DATE = as.character(DATE)) %>% 
  gather(VARIABLE, VALUE, -c(ID, RANK_DATE)) %>% 
  unite(VARIABLE, VARIABLE, RANK_DATE) %>% 
  spread(VARIABLE, VALUE) %>% 
  select(ID, 
         FIRST_DATE = DATE_1, FIRST_RESULT = RESULT_1, 
         SECOND_DATE = DATE_2, SECOND_RESULT = RESULT_2)

# Second Portion
df_RESULT <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE),
         RANK_RESULT = row_number(RESULT)) %>% 
  filter(RANK_RESULT %in% 1:2) %>% 
  mutate(DATE = as.character(DATE)) %>% 
  gather(VARIABLE, VALUE, -c(ID, RANK_RESULT)) %>% 
  unite(VARIABLE, VARIABLE, RANK_RESULT) %>% 
  spread(VARIABLE, VALUE) %>% 
  select(ID, 
         LOWEST_DATE = DATE_1, LOWEST_VALUE = RESULT_1, 
         SECOND_LOWEST_DATE = DATE_2, SECOND_LOWEST_VALUE = RESULT_2)

# Combine the 2 portions
df_out <- full_join(df_DATE, df_RESULT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have not missed anything we can do this in one chain without any reshaping or joining

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  #arrange(ID, DATE) %>% #if need to be sure that data is arranged by `ID` and `DATE`
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(FIRST_DATE = first(DATE), 
            FIRST_RESULT = RESULT[max(which(DATE == FIRST_DATE))], 
            SECOND_DATE = unique(DATE)[2], 
            SECOND_RESULT = RESULT[max(which(DATE == SECOND_DATE))], 
            LOWEST_DATE = DATE[which.min(RESULT)], 
            LOWEST_RESULT = RESULT[which.min(RESULT)], 
            SECOND_LOWEST_DATE = DATE[order(RESULT)[2]], 
            SECOND_LOWEST_RESULT = RESULT[order(RESULT)[2]])

# A tibble: 2 x 9
#     ID FIRST_DATE FIRST_RESULT SECOND_DATE SECOND_RESULT LOWEST_DATE LOWEST_RESULT SECOND_LOWEST_D… SECOND_LOWEST_R…
#  <int> <date>            <int> <date>              <int> <date>              <int> <date>                      <int>
#1     1 2018-03-01          120 2018-03-02            117 2018-03-03            100 2018-03-04                    100
#2     2 2018-11-01          108 2018-11-02            115 2018-11-04             70 2018-11-03                     80
```

To explain :

`FIRST_DATE` - selects the `first` value from `DATE`

`FIRST_RESULT = RESULT[max(which(DATE == FIRST_DATE))` - gets the indices where `DATE` is equal to `FIRST_DATE` and selects the `max` index to get last row in case of ties.

`SECOND_DATE = unique(DATE)[2]` gets the second distinct `DATE`

`SECOND_RESULT = RESULT[max(which(DATE == SECOND_DATE))]` - gets indices where `DATE` is equal to `SECOND_DATE` and selects `max` index to get last row in case of ties.

`LOWEST_DATE = DATE[which.min(RESULT)]` - Get the lowest `DATE`. `which.min` returns index of first minimum `DATE`

`LOWEST_RESULT` - Get the corresponding `RESULT` of `LOWEST_DATE`

`SECOND_LOWEST_DATE = DATE[order(RESULT)[2]]` - using `order` we arrange the `RESULT` in ascending order and select the second entry. This would work both for ties as well as a different entry in `RESULT`.

`SECOND_LOWEST_RESULT` - get the corresponding `RESULT` entry.